# Unable to copy contents from `Out-GridView` window

Tags: powershell

I can't copy the data from the grid window when using CTRL+C. It just closes the window.
My code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Add-Member -InputObject $_ -Name TerminalServicesProfilePath -Force -Membertype NoteProperty -Value (([ADSI]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)").TerminalServicesProfilePath) -PassThru
} | Select-Object -Property SamAccountName, TerminalServicesProfilePath | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Powershell version?

Comment: it's version 5.1.16299.967

Comment: Unable to repro.  Are you using CTRL+C with the `ogv` window selected? or the console?

Comment: i do select from ogv window then ctrl+c. Maybe one of my Modules are making problems. I tryied -noprofile but still same problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not solve your problem, but instead of using `Add-Member` (which is of limited use in this case), try using a calculated property in your pipeline:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * | Select-Object -Property @(
    'SamAccountName'
    @{
        Label      = 'TerminalServicesProfilePath'
        Expression = { ([adsi]"LDAP://$($_.DistinguishedName)").TerminalServicesProfilePath }
    }
) | Out-GridView
```

If you're using this in a script, or something of that nature, then your problem is *not* using the `Wait` switch on `Out-GridView`.  [See the documentation here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-gridview?view=powershell-3.0#parameters)

Comment: Nice that works. Still no idea why i had this issue.

Comment: @seyo-IV My *guess* is the process of adding the member to the objects was making the window focus go back to the console so when you hit CTRL+C you were actually cancelling the action.

Comment: If [ctrl]+[C] breaks. try [ctrl]+[INS].